# Javascript does not work in the second page of a data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-events, symfony-2.8

Actually I'm working with the following datatable: 
[image: Datatable]

```
Data Table code:
<table aria-describedby="dataTable_info" cellspacing="0" class="table table-hover dataTable" id="dataTable" role="grid" style="width:100%;" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{{'fsaGeneralPlan.table.Auditors'|trans({}, 'FSABundle')}}</th>
                <th>{{'fsaGeneralPlan.table.Audits'|trans({}, 'FSABundle')}}</th>
                <th>{{'fsaGeneralPlan.table.Areas'|trans({}, 'FSABundle')}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for audit in auditsByArea %}
            {% set myArray = audit.Audits|split(',') %}
            {% set AuditsStatus = audit.AuditsStatus|split(',') %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ audit.Auditor }}</td>
                        <td>
                        {# {% set long = numberOfAudits|length + 2  %} #}
                        {# <h1>{{ long }}</h1> #}
                            {% for i in 0..3 %}
                            {% set e = i + 1 %}
                            <a  title="{{ AuditsStatus[i] }}" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm auditButton {{ AuditsStatus[i] }}" data-id="Audit{{ myArray[i] }}" data-area="{{ audit.area_name }}"  data-status="{{ AuditsStatus[i] }}" id="auditButton{{ myArray[i] }}" name="auditButton">{{'w' ~ e }}</a>

                            {# <input  class ="auditButton {{ AuditsStatus[i] }} mx-2" value="{{'W' ~ i }}" href="" data-id="Audit{{ myArray[i] }}" data-area="{{ audit.area_name }}" data-status="{{ AuditsStatus[i] }}" id="auditButton{{ myArray[i] }}" name="auditButton" type='text' readonly ></input> #}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ audit.area_name }}</td>
                    </tr> 
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And I have this Javascript to change the class of the buttons in the datatable once that the page is loaded:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){


             $(".auditButton.Submitted").removeClass('btn-outline-primary');
             $(".auditButton.Submitted").addClass('btn-outline-success');
             $(".auditButton.Expired").addClass('btn-outline-danger');
             $(".auditButton.Capturable").addClass('btn-outline-warning');
        });
```

It works correctly but just in the first page of the datatable, it does not work in the other pages.

**Any idea or subject of how to fix it or what is wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the `draw` event for your table.

Why?
Your current setup works fine for the first page, because those elements are all rendered when `$(document).ready()` fires. However, the other pages are rendered after the document is ready.

Try:

```
const table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();

// Event listener for DT 1.10+
table.on('draw', function() {
    $(".auditButton.Submitted").removeClass('btn-outline-primary');
    $(".auditButton.Submitted").addClass('btn-outline-success');
    $(".auditButton.Expired").addClass('btn-outline-danger');
    $(".auditButton.Capturable").addClass('btn-outline-warning');
});
```

Doing this, you can also remove the same block of code from `$(document).

You can also place all this inside the draw callback for your datatable if you'd prefer:

```
const table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    drawCallback: function(settings) {
        // changes in here
    }
});
```

Comment: but if I remove $(document).ready(), I get an error in the console $(...).DataTable is not a function

Comment: @IrvingSotoGuzman Should be a simple fix! Let's place the entire block of code I gave you into the `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: thaaaaanks! it works, just there is a little problem, it works until I change the page of the datatable, but I will check it, for now it changes the class of the buttons :)

Comment: Draw is to redraw the datatable automatically after do a filtering or change the page, but you know how to apply  the same concept without make a filter or changing the sorting? @Cameron

Comment: @IrvingSotoGuzman The draw event is for whenever the table is drawn (e.g. when it first loads, sorting changes, or pagination) which answers your question I believe? If you want to force the draw event, you can call `$('#dataTable').DataTable().draw()`

Comment: yes it answers correctly the question and solved my problem, just that I would like to make that the data table appears with the buttons as when I sort the the table, it means withe buttons with their new class